How to return on object with a generic mapped type?
I have a mapped type defined as
type FooOrBar =  "foo" | "bar"

type ObjectWithHi<T extends FooOrBar> = {
        [key in T]: 'hi';
}

And then I would like to have a function call like
getFooOrBar<'foo'>('foo')

I tried to define my function as
function getFooOrBar<T extends FooOrBar>(fooOrBar: T): ObjectWithHi<T> {
    return {
        [fooOrBar]: 'hi',
    }
}

But TypeScript complains about
Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ObjectWithHi<T>'.

What am I doing wrong?

I think all keys in typescript just get widened to string, number or symbol during object creation. I don't know the details so well or underlying workings. There might be some fancy workaround but not sure, but in my experience in this case just casting the return to ObjectWithHi<T> is the simplest way to get your desired result.
You can also add as const to the value:
return {
    [fooOrBar]: 'hi' as const,
} as ObjectWithHi<T>

to get a stricter check so it actually checks the value and won't let you cast ObjectWithHi<T> if the value is not hi.
If you want to look more into this I think this github issue is the closest I could find where it's discussed a bit https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5579.

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948 is the most relevant issue here
